# Where has init_MUTEX gone in linux kernel version 3.2?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

I am following the *Linux Device Drivers (3rd edition)*. When I try to imitate the *scull* example in chapter 6 , an error is reported. It says that:

```
    error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_MUTEX’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

Can anyone tell me where has init_MUTEX gone?
By the way, Is there a list that I can check all the kernel API changes?

Comment: My development platform is Debian wheezy with kernel version 3.2.0-4. I know that the examples in this book is targeting at kernel 2.6. But I want to try all the instances in kernel 3.2 for studying.

Comment: The old semaphore-based mutexes were replaced by the new Mutex API like others said. Look at Documentation/locking/mutex-design.txt for more infos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`init_MUTEX{_LOCKED}()` was initially implemented as a semaphore](http://lwn.net/Articles/163807/). Semaphores were only in older 2.6.16 kernels, now mutex replace with earlier semaphores implementation, check the below api's and `linux/mutex.h` header

```
struct mutex { ...
};

mutex_{init,lock,trylock,unlock,lock_interruptible}()
```

Comment: thx for your answer. I think there are chucks of difference between kernel 2.6 and kernel 3.2.

Comment: @askb, is there any reason why linux moved from mutex as simple semaphore into totally new object ?

Answer (score 2):

Use mutex_init() instead:

```c
struct scull_pipe {
    ...
    struct mutex mutex;
    ...
};

mutex_init(&(lptr->device.mutex));
```

Comment: No need to have internal parentheses.

Comment: Those are from the original.